# Look up/search one of three criteria and return appropriate value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for the correct formula for a table I am working on. What I would like is:

`0` for say B1 if A1 equals "None",
 `1` if A1 equals "In" and
 `2` if A1 equals "out".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula will look something like this:
`=IF(G18="None",0,IF(G18="ln",1,IF(G18="out",2,0)))`

Just replace `G18` with the correct cell address that contains the `None|ln|out` value.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=CHOOSE(1+SEARCH(A1,"noneinout"),0,,,,,1,,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little shorter:

```
=(A1<>"None")*(A1="In")+2*(A1="Out")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just one more.

```
=(A1="in")+(A1="out")*2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested if formula

```
=IF(A1="None", 0, IF(A1="In", 1, IF(A1="out", 2, -1) ))
```